# Custom attributes for products Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, import, products

I'm trying to import around 5k products using Magento's native import. Unfortunately, I can't use third-party tools otherwise I would, I imagine this would simplify the process significantly.

My issue is, I'm trying to import a .csv from a wholesaler who has included a lot of extra information within the CSV I would like to provide potential customers. For example:

- Multiple quantities say a pack of 5, pack of 10, pack of 15. I would like this to be a drop-down on my actual site for a user to select before adding to the basket - there doesn't seem to be a csv header for this.
- Manufacturer, allowing me to group products by their respective manufacturer.
- Other custom attributes that I could show under a "details" tab (Like the warranty, expected battery life, screen size) - these would not be applicable to all products, but relevant.

I've tried to look at [this](https://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2016/01/magento-2-import-configurable-products/) for reference, as well as [this](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html) but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: May be this Paid Plugin Gonna Work Out for You https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html or http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-import-export-bulk-product-attributes-magento-2.html

Comment: @AnkitShah I'd rather use Magentos native functionality for the time being if possible

Comment: ok then go for it :)